# Ionic SMS and CallNumber problem in app.module.ts

Tags: javascript, android, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I have a problem SMS and CallNumber providers not identify my app.
I call

```
import { SMS } from '@ionic-native/sms';
import { CallNumber} from '@awesome-cordova-plugins/call-number';
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OWQNa.png)
app.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
  

  declarations: [AppComponent, OtvorenemestoComponent, GoogleMapComponent, ],
  entryComponents: [],
  imports: [BrowserModule, IonicModule.forRoot(), AppRoutingModule, 
    HttpClientModule,
    IonicStorageModule.forRoot(),
    TranslateModule,
    

    TranslateModule.forRoot ({
      loader:{
        provide: TranslateLoader,
        useFactory:httpLoaderFactory,
        deps:[HttpClient]
    }

    
    }),
    
  ],
  providers: [
     StatusBar,SplashScreen, Camera, File,
    HttpClient,  
    { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy },
    SMS,CallNumber,
   
EmailComposer
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

How is the problme? Please help my.thanks

Comment: Try importing them by adding `/ngx` at the end:

`import { SMS } from '@ionic-native/sms/ngx';`

`import { CallNumber} from '@awesome-cordova-plugins/call-number/ngx';`

or import them only where you need them (tab3.module).

Comment: I tried it this where i need too (tab3.module) and not is funkcionary. I tried this with / ngx and not go.

Comment: Did you correctly import classes for RouteReuseStrategy and IonicRouteStrategy? Try moving SMS and CallNumber above the `{ provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy }` line to make sure.

Comment: you were right, it works

Comment: solution is to use sms and callnumber in the module where I need it and with the extension / ngx